# InputNumber @ref Cannot convert expression type error

Tags: blazor

Consider the following blazor page:

```
@page "/Age"

<InputNumber id="year" class="form-control" @bind-Value="age" @ref="ageInput" />

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="@ShowMessage">Show Message</button>

<p>@displayMessage</p>

@code {

    InputNumber<int?> ageInput = null!;

    private int? age;

    private string? displayMessage;

    void ShowMessage() =>
    displayMessage = "Age = " + ageInput.Value;
}
```

When I view the .razor file in Visual Studio 2022 a red squiggle appears under the `@ref="ageInput"` and the error says:

```
Cannot convert expression type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.InputNumber<System.Nullable<int>>' to return type '{System.Threading.Tasks.Task,void}'
```

However the website builds without error and the page functions in the correct manner.

How do I get rid of this error from Visual Studio?

Target Framework: net7.0

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly version: 7.0.1

Comment: You've probably done some copying and renaming of files?  VS can get very confused about Razor files.  I've used your code in a component and no errors.  Create a new component and copy the code in, then delete the old file.  I always rename files in File Explorer, not VS.  It seems to work.  Also `ageInput.Value` is not a safe way to get the value.  Value is an "input" parameter used by binding to pass the current value of `age` into the component.  Just use `age`.

Comment: Try specifiying the TValue parameter of the InputNumber component.

Comment: MrC - no, it's not a copying issue.  I wrote this code from fresh in a new solution and razor file.  I know using ageInput.Value is bad usage.  I just wanted to come up with the simplest demo that would illustrate the point that the @ref="ageInput" was erroring.  I think it may be a ReSharper issue.  When I disable ReSharper the red squiggle goes away.

Comment: Sometimes it happens to me too. Part of it has to do with Resharper. However, many of them are solved with `rebuild` the entire solution. Please note that `rebuild` not build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appears to be a ReSharper bug.  See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-490460/Wrong-error-Cannot-convert-expression-type-MudBlazor.MudTextFieldstring-to-return-type-System.Threading.Tasks.Taskvoid-with-.NET